# Configure.xml for installing Office365 an an Azure remote desktop

Tags: office365, azure, office-deployment-tool

We have a server in Azure that runs remote desktop that our users log into via the rdweb interface. I would like to install the complete Office365 there in such a way that every user would need to enter their credentials upon the fist use the properly register the product.

Here's the configure.xml that I came with. Can you tell me if it's correct for the goal I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<Configuration>
    <Add OfficeClientEdition="64" Channel="Monthly">
        <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail">
            <Language ID="en-us" />
        </Product>
       <Product ID="VisioProRetail">
           <Language ID="en-us" />
       </Product>
       </Add>
    <Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="True" /> 
    <Property Name="SharedComputerLicensing" Value="1" />
</Configuration>
```

Comment: I don't believe Office 365 even be registered to multiple users on the same system.

Answer (score 0):

The configure.xml seems like no problem. If you use RDS to provide shared computers to users in your organization, I think you should also consider other aspects besides configure.xml. You can review [Deploy Office 365 ProPlus by using Remote Desktop Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/deploy-office-365-proplus-by-using-remote-desktop-services) and [Overview of shared computer activation for Office 365 ProPlus](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-of-shared-computer-activation-for-office-365-proplus)